# uninitialized constant issue in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 application where I'm following this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables

I have the following inside my index method in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { render json: ProductsDatatable.new(view_context) }
end
```

and inside app/datatables I have a file named products_datatable.rb like:

```
class ProductsDatatable
end
```

but I get the error:

```
NameError in ProductsController#index

uninitialized constant ProductsController::ProductsDatatable
```

Comment: change `ProductsDatatable.new(view_context)` to `::ProductsDatatable.new(view_context)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bjhaid mentioned,change change `ProductsDatatable.new(view_context) to ::ProductsDatatable.new(view_context)` and it will work